Tikz-qtree lines to the right direction are not straight with multiline texts
I have this following tex document:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\LARGE \bf Uraian pohon sintaksis}\\

\begin{exe}

\ex{{\bf (RU)}
\tikzset{grow'=right}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align = left, anchor=base west}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=170pt}}
\tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
\Tree [.K [.FN {\?{\it Путин}\\ Putin} ] [.FV [.V {\?{\it опроверг}\\ membantah} ] [.FN [.FN [. N {\?{\it дискриминацию}\\ diskriminasi\textsc{.aku}} ] [.N {\?{\it геев}\\ gay\textsc{.jam.gen}} ] ] [.FV [.P {\?{\it в}\\ di} ] [.N\textsc{.part} {\?{\it России}\\ Rusia\textsc{.prep}} ] ] ] ] ] }

\end{exe}

\end{document}

With this following typeset:

Everything went nice until the lines meet with multiline words. How can I improve my document so that the words are distributed equally and the lines are all straight?
I want the lines to be straight like this:

I have tried \tikzset{sibling distance=18pt} argument but it just made the distance larger, it did not make the lines straight:


Welcome! So do you want to keep the multiline nodes?

Off-topic: two-letter font macros (\bf etc.) were deprecated a few decades ago and shouldn't be used in LaTeX. You shouldn't use \\  to end a paragraph or, generally, to break lines outside special environments (tabular etc.). And you should use e.g. \section{} etc.

Yes, what I want is to that the lines connecting the multilines nodes to their parents node to be straight. Would you please read my question and possibly help me with that @cfr?

I did read it. I was confused by the second image. I guessed you meant you wanted to combine the lines from that with the multiline nodes from the other images, but I wanted to clarify that.

I added the other last two images hoping to put things to perspective. The second image is what I closely wanted my syntax tree to be, where the lines from their parents nodes are straight. Apparently, as shown here, increasing their sibling distance did not work either to make the lines straight either @cfr.

That's fine. I understand. Alan may know how to do this with tikz-qtree. The problem is the lines are drawn to the anchors and the anchors don't align because the children are taller than the parents. I thought you could use label instead ....

What happens if you use anchor=west rather than anchor=base west? I guess it is drawing to the west anchor, so if you aligned everything on that, the lines ought to be straight? (Just thought of this - didn't think to try it earlier.)

Anchor = west worked!!! I did not thought about the omitting the base. Anchor=base west did not. Thanks :) @cfr

Me neither ;). I tried much more complicated stuff which all failed. After I'd posted the forest answer, I suddenly thought what ought to work in tikz-qtree. base west would be fine if parent and child were the same height, but they're not. But if you align them in the middle, it doesn't matter.

[Edit See tikz-qtree solution below. But forest is more flexible.]
In forest, it is easy to format the tree according to your will. For what it is worth, here is a forest solution. Note that, on my machine, your code uses mf fonts rather than a scalable format, which probably isn't what you want, but that may be a function of minimising the example. I've further minimised the code for purposes of this question.
The syntax is not dissimilar to qtree/tikz-qtree, but there are no dots and children need square brackets even in the absence of branching.
\documentclass[border=10pt,10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    grow=0,
    anchor=base west,
  },
  where n children=0{%
    tier=terminus,
    calign with current edge,
    align=left,
  }{%
    font=\scshape,
  },
  [K
    [FV
      [FN
        [FV
          [P [\?{\itshape в}\\ di] ]
          [N.part [\?{\itshape России}\\ Rusia\textsc{.prep}] ]
        ]
        [FN
          [N [\?{\itshape геев}\\ gay\textsc{.jam.gen}] ]
          [N [\?{\itshape дискриминацию}\\ diskriminasi\textsc{.aku}] ]
        ]
      ]
      [V [\?{\itshape опроверг}\\membantah] ]
    ]
    [FN [\?{\itshape Путин}\\ Putin ] ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

I've also updated obsolete font commands.
I won't post a picture because a bug in the latest Okular on X means my pictures all look terrible, regardless of the actual output, so there isn't much point. Apologies for the omission.
EDIT
If you want to use tikz-qtree, setting anchor=west rather than anchor=base west does the trick:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\ex{{\bfseries (RU)}
  \tikzset{%
    grow'=right,
    every tree node/.style={anchor=west,align=left},
    frontier/.style={distance from root=170pt},
    execute at begin node=\strut,
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.K [.FN {\?{\itshape Путин}\\ Putin} ] [.FV [.V {\?{\itshape опроверг}\\ membantah} ] [.FN [.FN [. N {\?{\itshape дискриминацию}\\ diskriminasi\textsc{.aku}} ] [.N {\?{\itshape геев}\\ gay\textsc{.jam.gen}} ] ] [.FV [.P {\?{\itshape в}\\ di} ] [.N\textsc{.part} {\?{\itshape России}\\ Rusia\textsc{.prep}} ] ] ] ] ] 
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{exe}

\end{document}

I don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place ....

The code works, thanks! I might take a look into the forest more.

@pindakazen I've also posted a tikz-qtree solution which should have been more obvious, I guess, but I got lost trying complicated things which failed.

Thank you @cfr!
